# Invalid selector exception for clicking an element using Selenium with Cucumber for W3Schools site

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, cucumber-java

I am trying with the following Selenium Code using Cucumber for W3Schools site. When I click on "Try it yourself" button then it navigates to another page opening different window and the **window control also goes to the new window opened**. So,In the new window opened, if i click the run button, it throws an exception:

> invalid Selector

code:

```
//This clicks on the Try it yourself button
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[4]/p/a")
    private WebElement TryItYourself;
public void TryItYourSelfClick()
        {
            TryItYourself.click();  
        }
//Now,a new window opens up where I want to click on Run Button
    @FindBy(how=How.LINK_TEXT,using="Run >>")
    private WebElement RunButton;
public void RunClick()
        {
            RunButton.click();
        }

Calling Run Method
@Then("^a new window should appear$")
    public void a_new_window_should_appear() {
        System.out.println("Run button before Clicking");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        obj1.RunClick();
        System.out.println("Run after clicking");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         Set <String> handle=driver.getWindowHandles();
         String firstWinHandle=driver.getWindowHandle();
         String WinHandle=handle.iterator().next();
         if(WinHandle!=firstWinHandle)
         {
             driver.switchTo().window(WinHandle);
             System.out.println("Working for new window opened");
         }

}
```

why this invalid selector exception is coming?

HTML code:

```
<div class="w3-bar w3-light-grey" style="border-top:1px solid #f1f1f1;overflow:auto">
  <a id="tryhome" href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank" title="w3schools.com Home" class="w3-button w3-bar-item topnav-icons fa fa-home" style="font-size:28px;color:#999999;margin-top:-2px"></a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openMenu()" id="menuButton" title="Open Menu" class="w3-dropdown-click w3-button w3-bar-item topnav-icons fa fa-menu" style="font-size:28px;color:#999999;margin-top:-2px"></a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="click_savebtn()" title="Save" class="w3-button w3-bar-item topnav-icons fa fa-save" style="font-size:28px;color:#999999;margin-top:-2px"></a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="restack(currentStack)" title="Change Orientation" class="w3-button w3-bar-item topnav-icons fa fa-rotate" style="font-size:28px;color:#999999;margin-top:-2px"></a>
  <button class="w3-button w3-bar-item w3-green w3-hover-white w3-hover-text-green" onclick="submitTryit(1)">Run »</button>
  <span class="w3-right w3-hide-medium w3-hide-small" style="padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;display:block"></span>
  <span class="w3-right w3-hide-small" style="padding:8px 0;display:block;float:right;"><span id="framesize">Result Size: <span>433 x 439</span></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Which line throws `invalid Selector Exception`?

Comment: RunButton.click();

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with cucumber, but does it have an option to use cssSelector?

I looked at the button and found

```
body .trytopnav button
```

as a valid selector.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
invalid Selector Exception
```

...implies that the **how=How.LINK_TEXT,using="Run >>"** was not a valid selector.

The main issue is the element is not a `LINK_TEXT` but a `<button>` tag with text as **`Run »`**.

### Solution

Change the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as follows:

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//button[contains(.,'Run »')]")
//or
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//button[contains(.,'Run')]")
private WebElement RunButton;
```

Comment: Update with another option. Let me know the status

Answer (score 0):

look here https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.jsp we need to avoid using >> as possible, so try to use another locator by avoiding these

Comment: I had tried with other locator class which doesnot have this >> invalid characters as a locator.But still,its not working

Comment: <button class="w3-button w3-bar-item w3-green w3-hover-white w3-hover-text-green" onclick="submitTryit(1)">Run »</button>

Comment: use this xpath //a[@id='menuButton']/parent::div/button

Comment: Its still not working with the above mentioned xpath

Comment: exception?? please provide complete exception, if possible url where your are working

Comment: On entering this URL,https://www.w3schools.com/

Click on Try It yourself button where a new window will appear.And on that window there is Run>> button which we are trying to click on

Comment: i didnt get any exception on running it driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='menuButton']/parent::div/button")).click();

Comment: Are you able to click on the Run Button?It will only throw exception if u run on debug mode.

Comment: i ran normally, no exception. executed perfectly.

Comment: Are you clicking on Try it yourself button or Run button of the new window?

Comment: The code which you had pasted above is only clicking on Try it yourself button

Comment: sorry yea its clicking on run button only in your code.....Thanks...I will try nd figure out why its not working for me